# How to read a dynamic string as an object reference

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I need to set a button's value as a dynamic string. This string should be turned into an object reference. When the button is clicked the object will be loaded into a new variable. As of right now, it is reading in the string and not reading it as a reference.

Object:

```
var Wall ={
    "Option1":{},
    "Option2":{},
    "Option3":{
      "Option1_3":{
        Option1_1_3:{
           aTotal:100,
           Total_Something_Else:20,
           Another_Total:40,
           More_totals:20,
           Total:20,
         },
         "Option2_1_3":{},
         "Option3_1_3":{}
      },
      "Option2_3":{},
    },
    "Option4":{},
    "Option5":{}};
```

Code to create the button:

```
var options = ['1','2','3','4']

for (var a = 1; a < 2; a++) {
  for (var b = 3; b <4; b++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      document.getElementById('Option1_3').innerHTML = (`<button class="button"  value='${JSON.stringify('Wall.Option'+options[i]+'.Option'+a+'_'+b)}' onclick= "PopulateGraph(this.value)">Wall Time</button>`);
    }
  }
}
function PopulateGraph(val){
  console.log(Wall.Option3.Option1_3); //The ouptut of this is what I want
  console.log(JSON.parse(val));
```

}

The above code needs to behave like this piece of code:

[Code that works the way I need it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a44FN.png)

Output: The top output is what I would need:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF9W1.png)

---

Please be mindful that I am very new to coding and javascript. If you have any suggestions at all to make my code better in the long run or have references you think will be helpful please do not be shy. I apologize if this seems like a no-brainer. I have tried a few different solutions to my issue (using eval() and scope[] )and I have yet to figure out a solution. I am giving a very simplified version of my code but the issue is the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Can the `Wall` object change during the time that the user uses this page?

Comment: @trincot yes it will. The object will be populated with values from CSVs.

Comment: I would like to better understand the relationship between the `Wall` object and the elements that it relates to, as apparently there are elements on the page that have the same (or similar) id, as the properties in the `Wall`. Can you explain or even better provide the HTML where all the properties have their matching HTML element? I believe there is a better way to approach what you are doing.

Comment: @trincot In my main code, I am creating 3 buttons for every option#_# object. I'm dealing with sensitive material, and the objects end up being 10k+ lines so I did not want to post it all. If I can get past this problem I will be set.

Comment: So you don't have buttons for the deeper option#_#_# nor for the first level option#? Do you have HTML elements with id attributes that are valued "option#_#" for every such entry in the `Wall` object? You should indeed not paste 10k lines here. But it would be helpful to get a better idea what is needed, so we can answer with potentially a better approach.

Comment: Moreover you said the `Wall` object will change, so your `value` attribute may get assigned a reference too soon, when the `Wall` object has not yet been populated. To give a useful answer, we really need a few things more clarified.

Comment: The buttons correspond to data inside the Wall object. The deepest data (the totals) will change because the data in the CSVs may change. At the moment there are 90 buttons are there will be more. There are three objects Wall, CPU, and Disk. These 3 objects all look the same they just have different data. Each option#_# will have a button. No objects higher or lower will have buttons. I am generating the buttons automatically with  3 for loops like the one I provided. Since each button corresponds to a dataset inside the object I set the value of the buttons to the object it corresponds to.

Comment: I hope this makes sense. I'm not too familiar with all the coding lingo. I just need the value of the objects to be sent to the val variable. From there I will be using the totals to populate a graph on the page. Each button will be populating a graph to display the data on the page.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer with what I understand. I hope I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [bracket notation `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the properties.

```
JSON.stringify(Wall['Option'+options[i]]['Option'+a+'_'+b])
```

Additionally i would create a variable with the text to avoid doing all that work in the same line

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  const optionValue = Wall['Option' + options[i]]['Option' + a + '_' + b];
  const optionJson = JSON.stringify(optionValue);
  document.getElementById('Option1_3').innerHTML = (`<button class="button"  value='${optionJson}' onclick= "PopulateGraph(this.value)">Wall Time</button>`);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. I am kicking myself for not thinking of this! When I tried this solution I got the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0. On this line: console.log(JSON.parse(val));

Comment: Line 2 needs the dot removed from ['.Option'...]

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

- The reference you try to build with *i*, *a* and *b* does not exist in your object. Your object has only a nested object for "Option3", but as *i* is initialised in the `for` loop as 0, you are not targeting that property.
- The argument passed to `JSON.stringify` should be the nested value in the object, but you are passing a string, and so *that string* will be stringified (to yet another string).
- I understand you have used single quotes to delimit the value of the `value` attribute, but (if the previous points are fixed) the targetted value within the `Wall` object could be a string having a single quote, and then your HTML will still be broken, as that will *end* the `value` attribute which you had delimited with single quotes.
- As the `Wall` object is dynamically populated, you risk to be building the buttons too soon -- before the `Wall` object is populated -- and so the `value` attributes might still be wrong even when the above issues are resolved.

These complexities can be avoided by not building your button as a HTML string, but using the DOM methods to create the button element together with its attributes.

Furthermore, it seems that the information you store in the `value` property can be derived dynamically without that attribute:

- We can find the parent element of the clicked button, get it's id attribute, and then we know the second-level property in the `Wall` object.
- The `Wall` object seems to be structured in a way that the first-level property name can be derived from a second-level property name.

Also, you can iterate the properties in the `Wall` object without the need of `a` or `b` integers.

Here is how it could be done:

```js
var Wall ={
    "Option1":{},
    "Option2":{},
    "Option3":{
        "Option1_3":{
            "Option1_1_3":{
                aTotal:100,
                Total_Something_Else:20,
                Another_Total:40,
                More_totals:20,
                Total:20,
            },
            "Option2_1_3":{},
            "Option3_1_3":{}
        },
        "Option2_3": {
            "Option2_1_3":{
                test:1
            }
        },
    },
    "Option4":{},
    "Option5":{}
};

for (let option of Object.values(Wall)) {
    for (let id in option) {
        let container = document.getElementById(id);
        if (container) {
            let button = document.createElement("button");
            button.className = "button";
            button.textContent = "Wall Time for " + id;
            button.addEventListener("click", PopulateGraph);
            container.appendChild(button);
        }
    }
}

function PopulateGraph() { // no argument.
    // Drill down in the Wall object, based on the id of the button's container
    let val = this.parentNode.id.match(/\d+/g).reduceRight(
        (acc, _, i, arr) => acc[`Option${arr.slice(i).join("_")}`],
        Wall
    );
    console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<div id="Option1_3"></div>
<div id="Option2_3"></div>
```